# Wordpress issue? XML Sitemap generator finding 1000's of infinate looping URLS ( there should be about 200 urls altogether)

Tags: php, xml, wordpress, apache, sitemap

I ran my website through http://www.xml-sitemaps.com and I know that my website has about 200 pages, this generator maxed out after 500 pages and others generators keeps finding thousands of URLS (I have to stop the crawl as it appears to never end).

It is because it is finding URLS such as this:

Current page: blog/index.php/barmah-hats-the-sensible-choice/www.website.co.uk/blog/index.php/barmah-hats-the-great-autralian-hat/www.website.co.uk/blog/index.php/barmah-hats-the-great-autralian-hat/www.website.co.uk/blog/index.php/barmah-hats-the-great-autralian-hat/www.website.co.uk/blog/index.php/barmah-hats-the-great-autralian-hat/www.website.co.uk/blog/index.php/barmah-hats-the-great-autralian-hat/www.website.co.uk/blog/index.php/barmah-hats-the-great-autralian-hat/

obviously the page is just

http://www.website.com/blog/index.php/barmah-hats-the-sensible-choice/

it appears to append another article URL onto the end

Is this the fault of the generator, or is something wrong with my htaccess rules? I ave no clue, any help would be appreciated.

I should note that this issue occurs only within the /blog/ directory which is a wordpress installation.

I am worried that these pages will start to index.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it, I had a link on a blog page that was point to "www.website.com" instead of "http://www.website.com" so It was pointing to /www.website.com thinking it was a directory.